# What do you know about avaloq scripts?

Tags: scripting, avaloq-script

I wonder who has programmed using avaloq script. What are its benefits? What is it used for?

WHat does it look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Avaloq Script is a script language used for customizing Avaloq Banking System, a standard core banking software mainly used in Switzerland. It's only used and useful within the Avaloq software.

It's basically PL/SQL without SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. But it additionally has an object-oriented syntax for accessing the Avaloq object model.

The language itself is pretty straightforward. However, it's difficult to use because of the complex, inconsistent and poorly documented object model.