# Avaloq Scripts - PLSQL

Tags: plsql, avaloq-script

What do you know about Avaloq Scripts ?

It's a good way to learn things? Does it has the same functions like sql, pl/sql (greatest, least, fetch only, bulk collect, collections etc ) ?

I got a good offer, but I don't want to move away from real PL/SQL.

Any information would help!

Thank u!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238284/what-do-you-know-about-avaloq-scripts) quite a long time ago (in 2009) so - possibly, many things have changed.

Have a look at link I posted.

Besides that, there's a *deleted* answer. I wouldn't delete it; looks someone mis-identified it as spam as it contained link to [blog](https://blog.serpland.com/avaloq/d-avaloq-script-sourcecode-avaloq-parametrierer-beispiel) written in German.

As you don't have reputation high enough to review deleted posts, here is its (deleted message's) contents:

> Avaloq Script can also be described as a layer language, encapsulating Oracle's PL/SQL.
> So in Avaloq Script you have only about 20% of the usual PL/SQL syntax available. Therefore Avaloq hides all of its thousands database objects behind a own Avaloq data dictionary. So all DML commands as sel, ins, upd, del are hidden behind this ddic. You program all this operations against the ddic.

---

The bottom line (from my point of view) is: it makes sense to dig into Avaloq Script if you plan to work with Avaloq software and - possibly - get employed in one of banks in Switzerland which use it as their core software. If your interests are elsewhere, I don't see a point in using it.